# WebSocket Fails to Send Completion Message After Redis Event in python app (Cloud Run & VM)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, websocket, redis, video-processing

I hope you are well, I'm new here, looking for help with a problem I can't seem to solve. I'm working on a Python web app that processes video files. It's deployed to cloud run and uses a vm for the video pre and post processing. Once the video processing completes it sends a completion websocket message and the user is directed to the next page. The app uses Redis for messaging and WebSocket for client updates. Pre-processing and post-processing messages are published to a Redis channel, and the WebSocket messages are sent to the client. The pre-proccessing message works and sends, but the post-processing isn't sending and the user is stuck on the processing page, even though the video process is completing successfully. There are no errors that I can see. The strange thing is the issue only occurs in the deployed environment and I can't reproduce it locally. It also seems to sometimes work, but at random.

I've checked the Redis setup and confirmed the connection & messages are working correctly. I've added a variety of logs to try to catch any possible errors, but it seems like it's completing successfully. The WebSocket communication also works for other parts of the application. Expecting the websocket to send a complete: true message once the video processing is completed successfully and direct you to the success page, but often the message doesn't get sent and you are stuck on the processing page.

Brief overview of the process:

-The app publishes a message to a Redis channel for pre-processing, which works fine.
-Logs a WebSocket message to show the start of post-processing.
-App publishes another message to Redis for the start of post-processing.
-The post-processing completes successfully, but no WebSocket message is sent to indicate the completion.

Relevant logs show the following:

Pre-processing Redis message published successfully.
Post-processing starts and a corresponding Redis message is published.
No WebSocket message for post-processing completion is logged.

Any help would be hugely appreciate.

With gratitude,

Comment: What's your Cloud Run timeout and what's the duration between 2 messages?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The cloud run timeout is 2000 seconds and the duration between the pre-processing messages is about 4 seconds (first the video data for processing and then the complete message) and then between the post-processing it can vary depending on the video size, but usually shouldn't take longer than 10 minutes max before completing. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I have no more idea. I used websocket and Cloud Run and it works well as long as the request timeout is not expired.